# Significado de "presente" en una carta. ¿Se escribe dos puntos después del destinatario?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, correspondencia

Por ejemplo, suelo encontrar los encabezados de las cartas como sigue:

```
                                                  Cierta ciudad, Cierto país, 
                                                  30 de marzo de 2013
 Dr. Juan López   
 Presidente de la Asociación de XY  
 Presente

 Estimado Dr. López, 

 blah blah...
```

1. ¿Qué significa *presente*? ¿Para qué se escribe?
2. Después del destinatario ¿qué signo de puntuación es el correcto? ¿dos puntos o coma?

   ```
    Estimado Dr. López:

    El motivo de mi carta ...
   ```

o bien

```
     Estimado Dr. López,

     el motivo de mi carta ...
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Debajo del nombre del destinatario va la dirección. Si la carta no se envía (se entrega en mano) se pone "presente".

```
Dr. Juan López                                 Dr. Juan López
Presidente de la Asociación de XY     vs       Presidente de la Asociación de XY
Presente                                       Calle 109, 1234
                                               CIUDAD
```

También es (era) común poner “S / D”, que significa “su despacho”.

Hoy en día probablemente se ponga “presente” en cartas enviadas por correo por desconocimiento y “tradición” (repetir algo que se ha visto pero cuya función se desconoce).

Tras el **vocativo**, que puede o no incluir el nombre del destinatario (ejemplo: “Estimado colega:”), se usan los dos puntos.

Answer (score 4):

En castellano se debe utilizar ":" en los encabezamientos, siendo el uso de "," una costumbre anglosajona.

La RAE refiriéndose a su uso dice en [1]:

> 1.4. Se emplean tras las fórmulas de saludo en el encabezamiento de cartas y documentos. En este caso, la palabra que sigue a los dos
>   puntos, y que inicia el cuerpo de la carta, se escribe con inicial
>   mayúscula y en renglón aparte (→ mayúsculas, 3.3a): Muy señor mío: /
>   Le agradeceré que en el plazo más breve posible... **Es costumbre
>   anglosajona, que debe evitarse en español, utilizar la coma en lugar
>   de los dos puntos**: Querido amigo, / Te escribo esta carta para
>   comunicarte...

En cuanto a qué significa "presente" decir que no le encuentro ningún sentido. En encabezamientos de cartas formales se utiliza la forma "por la presente..." refiriéndose a que "por medio de esta carta...". Ejemplo:

> Por la presente me dirijo a ustedes...

[1] http://www.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2a3yRXFBiD6rvDOMtq